# Automate any software

Tags: windows, automation

A quick question. Is there any method to control or automate any Windows application, using the command line. I've tried AutoIt. Any other methods? I'm targetting to control WinCE Test Kit (CETK) to perform the test without having to go to the GUI,or click the menu, connect etc, manually.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We use Rational Robot for this but keep in mind it's not cheap. It's also probably been renamed 27 times since we started using it so you may want to just search for Rational testing products in general.

It's fully script-able, allowing you to monitor the screen and send key presses and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Look at SCAR, it is great for all sorts of automation and screen reading: http://freddy1990.com/index.php?page=product&name=scar

Answer (score 0):

I've always used a hybrid approach.  First purchase [SOTI Pocket Controller Pro](http://www.soti.net/default.asp?Cmd=Products&SubCmd=PCPro) then just use the normal AutoIt automation tools.  It's a little different because you can't actually capture popup windows like you may be used to, but it can automate clicks, and then loop and wait for things using the GetPixel methods to check it the screen is what you expect.

Being able to connect to multiple CE devices at the same time visually is also a nice touch.